Consistency problem with debug symbol paths when debugging bazel build C++ with lldb
I'm using bazel 7.4.1-homebrew on MacOS 15.1.1 within VS Code.
The issue I'm having, is that I want to debug a target with lldb. I have setup my launch.json like this:
    {
      "name": "Bazel debug with lldb (MacOS)",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "targetArchitecture": "arm64",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-bin/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [],
      "preLaunchTask": "Build current Bazel file (debug)",
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "lldb",
      "sourceFileMap": {
        ".": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }

I have already disabled sandboxing since that generates ever changing paths with the different sandboxes.
Now my issue is that the paths I'm getting are not consistent:
The correct relative symlink path to the binary is:
bazel-bin/src/main/main
If that path is being resolved, the path is:
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_username/a400ea441e3cbaea85fa60d80a42ac3a/execroot/_main/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-dbg/bin/src/main
If I print the path of the binary at runtime it prints:
/Users/username/repos/cpp_udemy2/bazel-bin/src/main/main
The debug symbol queried from lldb - this path is existing and correct.
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_username/a400ea441e3cbaea85fa60d80a42ac3a/execroot/_main/src/main/main.cc
Now the confusion is, that VS Code is expecting source code being at this path. Note the missing /private in front of the path.
/var/tmp/_bazel_username/a400ea441e3cbaea85fa60d80a42ac3a/execroot/_main/src/main/main.cc
Even more confusing to me, is that this path is existing.
Why are there two different paths to debug symbols? One in /private/var/tmp/... and one in /var/tmp/...?
Is there any way to reliably resolve the symlink to the bazel-bin directory on launch, so that the path of the debug symbol is aligned with the source file I'm currently working on?
More information just in case:
.bazelrc
build --action_env=BAZEL_CXXOPTS="-std=c++20"

build --copt=-fdiagnostics-color=always
run --copt=-fdiagnostics-color=always

build --strip=never
build --spawn_strategy=standalone
build --sandbox_debug
build --features=oso_prefix_is_pwd

test --test_output=streamed

tasks.json
    {
      "label": "Build current Bazel file (debug)",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "bazel",
      "args": [
        "build",
        "-c",
        "dbg",
        "//${relativeFileDirname}:${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "shared"
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    }

